How to Export Only Checked Rows from APEX Report to CSV?
I am working on a report in Oracle APEX where I have added checkboxes for each row. I want to export only the rows that have the checkboxes selected into a CSV report.
Currently, I am using the following PL/SQL process to handle the export:
DECLARE
l_selected_ids     APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2; 
l_sql_query        VARCHAR2(32767);
l_bind_clauses     VARCHAR2(32767);
l_page_items_export apex_data_export.t_export;
l_page_items_context apex_exec.t_context;

BEGIN
l_selected_ids := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01;
IF l_selected_ids.COUNT > 0 THEN
    
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_selected_ids.COUNT LOOP
        l_bind_clauses := l_bind_clauses || ':' || i || ','; 
    END LOOP;
    l_bind_clauses := RTRIM(l_bind_clauses, ',');
    l_sql_query := 'SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO IN (' || l_bind_clauses || ')';
    
    l_page_items_context := apex_exec.open_query_context(
        p_location => apex_exec.c_location_local_db,
        p_sql_query => l_sql_query
    );

    l_page_items_export := apex_data_export.export(
        p_context => l_page_items_context,
        p_format  => apex_data_export.c_format_csv,
        p_as_clob => TRUE
    );

    apex_exec.close(l_page_items_context);
    apex_data_export.download(p_export => l_page_items_export);
ELSE
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'No rows selected for export.');
END IF;

END;
However, when the rows are selected and I try to export, I am getting an empty CSV report.
how I can properly export only the selected rows based on the checkboxes?

I would consider using an interactive grid. As from APEX 24.1, selected records can be stored in a page item with almost no code - here are the docs. Processing can then be done purely in pl/sql using APEX_TRING.SPLIT - a lot simpler than using APEX_ITEM
